# Rename the get object of json

Tags: typescript, angular

I have http service, and get some json:

```
    [{
    "nodename": "192.124.105.55",
    "servicelist": [{
        "id": "ec9471ec001c10b9fa286e1f52e39c5dc9485a7c2cfbf55145c26242bb98ec4d",
        "name": "Nginx",
        "status": "Online",
        "servicecontrolled": true
    },
{
        "id": "f4ca9e0badc6b23e3e36444bd7ee4a9efcd39de8e0bb4cdecb25b5a02ef86ba5",
        "name": "Memcached",
        "status": "Offline",
        "servicecontrolled": false
    }]
```

Show in html `servicecontrolled` only `true`:

```
 <td>
  <span *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled">{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json }}</span>
 </td>
```

And now ,y task is rename `true`to come another word, ex. `onn/off`.
How to do it?

Comment: You want to rename servicecontrolled in your json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled ? 'on/off' : 'false' }}
```

Or if you need it on multiple places you could create a pipe for it:

```
@Pipe({name: 'toOnOff'})
export class OnOffPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean): string {
    return value ? 'on/off' : 'false';
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | toOnOff }}
```

Comment: and now show only 'on', and i would show some 'on/off'

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question then? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: and how i can use two pipes at the same time? this `<span *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled">{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json, toOnOff }}</span>` not working

Comment: i want  to rename the "true" to "on/off" (one string)

Comment: Just use another `|` instead of a comma.

Comment: Okay, and what should happen, if it's false?

Comment: thanks :) tell me please, where i can get information about sytax like this `? 'on/off' : 'false';`?

Comment: This is just the [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). A shorthand `if`. It expands to something like: `if (value) { return 'on/off' } else { return 'false' }`